# Facebook crawler issues - wrong image, wrong description

Tags: facebook, web-crawler

I have some issues with Facebook crawler and can't figure out what's wrong.

First of all, when I post my site's address in Facebook chat window it displays a strange, unknown, thumbnail, also there's no description. Of course og:image tag on my side is set properly.

I've been using [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) to find out what's wrong and the debugged data is perfectly fine (even the thumbnail), but still it displays wrong thumbnail in the chat.

I've tried to re-index my website on Facebook by whitelisting crawlers/agents IPs, pasting URL into Debugger, changing og:image URLs, no luck whatsoever.

Also, there's one, more complex issue and I'm not sure how to figure it out.

My website has 12 language versions, you basically click on a button "change language" and it translates the site (including site's description!), the default language is set to English but Facebook's Debugger picks random language versions so after I click "Debug" I end up with Chinese description, then I click Debug again and it shows English description and so forth.

Is there a way of setting thumbnail and description manually? If not then maybe could I contact Facebook staff to help me out with these issues?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the image to use in your blog's HTML meta tags, see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/